# Error # 1045 - Cannot Log in to MySQL server after computer resart

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a small web application for college project and so far everything was working perfectly until i restart my computer and suddenly i get this error everytime i try to login to mySql

```
Error # 1045 - Cannot Log in to MySQL
```

Am using EasyPHP 13.1, and running windows 7 
and this is my config.inc.php, knowing that before this problem i used to login with 'root' as username and password

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
?>
```

and these lines used to work perfectly when i call it :

```
define('DB_NAME','demo');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');


    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    /*Test */
    if(!$link){
        /*Fermer tout et afficher ce message*/
        die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Success!!';
```

thank you

Comment: Is the server up? Do you have multiple MySQL installations?

Comment: Is the MySQL service started? I use XAMPP and don't have it set to auto-start the service on boot, so I go into XAMPP Control Panel and start the service after every reboot. It sounds like you're having the same issue, but with EasyPHP.

Comment: @matiasinsaurralde easyPHP say that the server is up (both green) and i don't know if i have multiple instalaltions :p 2 days ago i almost tried everything to get this working so maybe, Remark, the latest version of easyPHP can't start MySql (always red)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version of easyPHP and change the MySQL port, after that everything works perfectly, thank you